# AJAX select box is not updating in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, select

i've a select box filled by ajax. however i need to change select option using ajax. following code is working in IE but not is Firefox. please help.

```
var tts = $("select#myList option");   //collected all options
   tts.each(function(i){
        var cpid = this.attributes['pankti'].value; // check for desired rel tag
        if(cpid === ppid) { 
          this.attr('selected','selected');   //...and select this option
        }else{
          this.removeAttr('selected','');     //.. else clear selection
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
var tts = $("select#myList option");   //collected all options
   tts.each(function(i){
        var option= $(this);
        var cpid = option.attr('pankti'); // check for desired rel tag
        if(cpid === ppid) { 
          option.attr('selected','selected');   //...and select this option
        }else{
          option.removeAttr('selected','');     //.. else clear selection
        }
      });
```

Comment: thanx for your amazingly expeditious response. it sure solved. can u pls explain what was affecting firefox in previous code? also, i wish i could trigger a change event after changing the selection.

Comment: you have to use $(this) to get reference to jquery object and access methods like .attr

Comment: $("select#myList).change(); to trigger change effect

Comment: thanks Micheal, i had to go for .click() event as .change() was not doing as desired.

Comment: Micheal can you please look at this issue?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696093/ajax-click-event-not-firing-for-select-option

Answer (score 0):

You can also try changing the line that says:

```
option.attr('selected','selected');
```

to

```
option.prop('selected','selected');
```