# ajax click event not firing for select option

Tags: jquery, ajax, list, select

I have a select list(#searchHistory) appended by ajax:

```
var toAppend = '<option rel="' + relval + '">' + eVal + '</option>';
$("#searchHistory").append(toAppend);
```

and there is a click event registered for the select box

```
 $('#searchHistory option').click( function() {
    var shOpt = $(this);
    var relVal = shOpt.attr('rel');

    alert(relVal);
});
```

my problem is that the Last Item of the select box does not fire the click event!!!! all other items are working when clicked. Interestingly when i use a PREPEND instead on APPEND, the first item does not fire the click event and all other items do work. please note that the select box is populated by ajax code above. it means, if i add another  to the list box, then the previous non-working item works well but the recently added item still not work.

any ideas please ???
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#searchHistory').change( function() {
    var shOpt = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var relVal = shOpt.attr('rel');

    alert(relVal);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

appended items dont fire events normaly so you need to the "on" method try:

```
 $(function(){
$('body').on("change","#searchHistory", function() {
var shOpt = $(this);
var relVal = shOpt.attr('rel');

alert(relVal);
```

});
})

[jQuery "on"](http://api.jquery.com/on/)